# Are toughness and healing values switched between player and follower in the display?

Tags: diablo-iii-console

On console, below the equipment ring, there are three symbols with values (and please read the whole question before jumping to conclusions here).

- Sword (DPS)
- Shield
- Two plus signs

On my own character, at level 34, the values are 3177, 18.8k and 285 respectively. I would understand this to be dps (that I'm sure of), toughness, and healing.

**The reason I'm asking** is that when I move over to my follower, the exact same symbols have these values:

- Sword: 398
- Shield: 498
- Two plus'es: 13.7k

In other words, if the shield signifies toughness, then I have 18.8k and my follower 498? Or if the two plus'es signify toughness (unlikely if you ask me) do I really have only 285 toughness?

So, is this a bug in the display, follower and own character shield/plus values are switched?

Or does my follower really have 13.7k healing?

This is the Templar by the way.

Or have I gotten the icons completely wrong to begin with (except DPS)?

Here's some more hard numbers, my own Wizard (now level 37):

- Sword: 3995
- Shield: 26.5k
- Plus'es: 353
- Strength: 65
- Dexterity: 66
- Intelligence: 1670
- Vitality: 804

Templar:

- Sword: 579
- Shield: 767
- Plus'es: 20.7k
- Strength: 468
- Dexterity: 45
- Intelligence: 362
- Vitality: 1576
- Skills: Heal (heal 4402), Loyalty (+147 regen/sec), Charge, Inspire (resource regen)

Comment: Hard to answer with the data here. Your Templar can have his healing spell learned which will add to the healing value. The magical properties of his items can have big healing effects. It's very possible to be correct.

Comment: I'll edit in more data.

Comment: I just thought it was unlikely that either I or the templar had that low toughness (ie. if one is toughness and the other healing, one of us is quite low in my opinion)

Comment: Wizards in general have low toughness. Templars and all followers really have lower toughness until you start finding level 70 legendaries. They aren't meant to tank really hard.

Comment: I've noticed the same thing (xbox one version). It does look like a bug.